# Linux on Lenovo Z575 - no display after installation

Tags: laptop

I am trying to install Linux on Lenovo Ideapad Z575 (AMD). 
When I run Ubuntu or Fedora from a LiveCD, I got some initial screens (purple screen with small icon for Ubuntu, some information screen from Fedora), and then.... nothing. For Ubuntu, I have a black screen, although I hear the Ubuntish sound when the login screen appears. So it is there, but the display does not work.

Any ideas how to make the display working?

Comment: What video hardware does it have?

Comment: Integrated Radeon. The processor is AMD A6-3400 APU

Comment: Ah. There are two open-source drivers for that one, and there is the closed-source one. Which driver are you using? I recommend the open-source drivers for general use.

Comment: Frankly, I was running (unsuccessfully) Linux from LiveCD, so I run all the defaults. I didn't reach point of driver selection

Comment: I managed to install `crunchbang` Linux, and then install the ATI drivers. so I can proceed. But the issue is still opened, for those that want Ubuntu or Fedora.

Comment: I have Lenovo Ideapad Z575 too. Same problem U describe, but I tried GParted (Live USB). System started, splash screen was OK, then some txt messages and - suddenly - everything disappears and screen turned off. No response, no alert messages. Simply - black hole ;-) Can I do something BEFORE starting Live USB linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `nomodeset` and `xforcevesa` in grub options, so the system do not "turn black" after booting, and is running with the generic drivers. 
Then after launching the system, I installed official drivers from ATI and now all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If i have this problem, I press ctrl alt F1, wich gives me the commandline screen. And then without typing anything else, I press ctrl+alt+F7, and after a couple of seconds the screen seems to reset, and I can login again.
(PS: On my keyboard I have to press ctrl, then alt, then first the orange Fn key and thén the F7 key!)